# How to generate an ID for JSP input

Tags: java, jsp

How do you generate an Unique Id in JSP/Java which then input into a text, I have attemted to use UDDID however I want it to be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc.

Out current input code is the following

```
    <%

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String question = request.getParameter("question");
    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();


    String file_name = "form.txt";
    try{
        ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
        String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
        int i;
        for(i=0; i< aryLines.length; i++);

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Sorry,not accepted");
    }

    WriteFile fileWriter = new WriteFile(file_name, true);

    fileWriter.writeToFile(name+","+question+","+date+","+"Pending");
%>
```

Many Thanks

Comment: It is difficult from your example code to determine why you want a unique ID. Your file code above should not be in a JSP, that's not such a good practice. Could you clarify why you want a unique ID?

Comment: @Bartvl @Tom Hartwell Hi there, we want it inputed into the text file along with the others. So `fileWriter.writeToFile(ID+","name+","+question+","+date+","+"Pending"); `. So in the text file it will be like "1,first,question,Tue Feb 28 14:59:53 GMT 2012,Pending"

Comment: @user1235590 When you start looping through the lines that you read from the text file, use the value of i (or whatever variable you used for the loop) as your ID value. The loop will automatically increment it for you :)

Answer (score -1):

In general if you want incremented unique IDs in a Java application, [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)s work well.

Comment: Why on earth would you use something like an AtomicInteger for that? An int is more than suitable for the same job, and only uses a fraction of the memory.

Comment: I assumed that by unique ID the poster needed a number unique across an application.

Comment: But AtomicIntegers are for multiprogramming; there is no need of using a relatively heavy weight object when you only want to get a unique number. Unless by "The whole application" you mean the complete servlet, where multiple threads will access the same variable. Then my judgement was too fast.

Comment: No problem, yes by application I meant web application, since the original poster's example was a JSP. I should have mentioned to the poster why AtomicIntegers are useful, since that is pretty key information in deciding whether to use them or not.